# How to add the output of two commands info a file?

Tags: linux

I simply want to append the outputs of two command which are ps -A and du into a file called "info"

This is what I've got:

```
ps -A ; du > info
```

However, it only adds du into the file. What am I getting wrong?

Comment: Related: [Pipe/redirect a group of commands](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/164482/pipe-redirect-a-group-of-commands)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to use a subshell (another process) :

```
 { ps -A ; du; } > info
 #           ^
 #           |
 #        mandatory (in this one liner case)
```

or

```
{
    ps -A
    du
} > info
```

Comment: That worked as well, thanks again :)